# Chrome blocking PDF views on web redirection to new tab via Top-Frame Navigations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, pdf, iframe

As per the Chrome version >=60 the PDF view functionality by any top-frame navigations options like

```
<A HREF=”data:…”>
window.open(“data:…”)
window.location = “data:…”
```

has been blocked by Google for which the discussion can be found at [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/blink-dev/top$20level$20data/blink-dev/GbVcuwg_QjM/JY6uJ6Q4BwAJ). Now the problem is how to display the PDF on web without explicitly or forcibly making PDF to download. My old code looked as below via `window.open` to view the PDF data

```
dataFactory.getPDFData(id, authToken)
.then(function(res) {
    window.open("data:application/pdf," + escape(res.data));
},function(error){
    //Some Code
}).finally(function(){
    //Some Code
});
```

In above I extract the PDF data from server and display it. But since `window.open` is blocked by Chrome and as suggested by one of the expert over [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/k-9y57tme2E;context-place=topicsearch/author$3Ame) to use `<iframe>` to open the PDF data and I tried but it's not working. It always says Failed to Load PDF Data as below

[image]

The updated JS code for the `<iframe>` looks as below:

```
dataFactory.getPDFData(id, authToken)
.then(function(res) {
    $scope.pdfData = res.data;
},function(error){
    //Some Code
}).finally(function(){
    //Some Code
});
```

And the HTML looks as below:

```
<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,pdfData" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

How can I proceed and bring back the original PDF view functionality? I searched over other stack questions but out of luck on how to resolve this. May be I did something wrong or missed something with the iframe code but it's not working out.

Comment: Had similar problem with jsPdf library. Iframe solved problem for me. Can open PDF in new window, but I can not download it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After unable to find the desired result I came up with below approach to resolve the issue.
Instead of opening the PDF on new page what I did is as soon as user clicks on the Print button PDF file gets downloaded automatically. Below is the source for same.

```
//File Name
var fileName = "Some File Name Here";

var binaryData = [];
binaryData.push(serverResponse.data);      //Normal pdf binary data won't work so needs to push under an array

//To convert the PDF binary data to file so that it gets downloaded
var file = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: "application/pdf"}));
var fileURL = document.createElement("fileURL");
fileURL.href = file;
fileURL.download = serverResponse.name || fileName;
document.body.appendChild(fileURL);
fileURL.click();

//To remove the inserted element
window.onfocus = function () {                     
    document.body.removeChild(fileURL)
}
```

Comment: I think that `document.createElement("fileURL")` should be `document.createElement("a")`. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

In your old code :
"data:application/pdf," + escape(res.data)

In the new :
your iframe src is like "data:application/pdf;base64,pdfData"

Try to remove base64 from the src, it seems to be already present in the value of 'pdfdata'.